# Angular get date from datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the date from a bootstrap datetimepicker but when I put a ng-model on the input field it's not working?

**html**

```
<!-- EndDate -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dtp_enddate">Eind datum:</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="dtp_endDate">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="EndDate" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.EndDate" required="required" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
   $(function() {
        $('#dtp_endDate').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: true,
            collapse: true,
            format: 'YYYY-MM-D',
            locale: 'nl',
            allowInputToggle: true
        });
    });
```

How could I accomplish that?

Comment: could you create a plnkr  http://plnkr.co or or codepen http://codepen.io

Comment: also try avoiding usage of any 3rd party libraries along with angularjs, like in your case usage of jquery. **Whatever you can do with Jquery is possible with angularjs as well.**  more info for your reference :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need date-time-picker in a single component you can use http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/ or you can use 2 components (datepicker and timepicker) from [Angular Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

It is not the best practice to combine angularJS with jQuery plugins. There is a plenty of plugins converted to angularJS directives, which you could try to use.
E.g.
https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" />
in this example date is binding to dt (ng-model="dt")
```

you can get data by $scope.dt if you want to watch the date change you can do

```
$scope.$watch('dt',function(val){
   //to do       
   console.log(val)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Include id ="dtp_endDate" inside input tag

```
<input type="text" id="dtp_endDate" class="form-control" name="EndDate" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.EndDate" required="required" />
```